# XPath to modify Application Settings in Web Config

Tags: .net, xpath, ucd

I am using XPath to modify some settings in my application's config file during a UCD deploy, however I can't figure out the right path to use.

I am able to change the connection string no problem but the application settings uses a different syntax that I can't get XPath to match.

This is the XPath I used:

```xml
//configuration/applicationSettings/ServiceTaskFunctions.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='Hello']/@value->${p:environment/World}
```

`${p:environment/World}` being an environment property that I am confident works because the connection string works the same way.

I expected the following:

```xml
<setting name="Hello" serializeAs="String">
<value>World</value>
</setting>
```

But what I got was:

```xml
<setting name="Hello" serializeAs="String">
    <value></value>
</setting>
```

Answer (score 1):

The entity `value` is an element and not an attribute.
So change `/@value` to `/value` like this:

```
//configuration/applicationSettings/ServiceTaskFunctions.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='Hello']/@value
```

to

```
//configuration/applicationSettings/ServiceTaskFunctions.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='Hello']/value
```

Comment: That removed the <value> tags changing it to: `<setting name="Hello" serializeAs="String"> World`